# find -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755 at the default path has stopped access to databases

Tags: linux, file-permissions, undo

Like a total noob I was trying to set wordpress permissions from some sites on the internet. My session dropped out and I reconnected but at the default path and not in the directory. I went back to the guide and ran this command.

find -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755

I realised pretty quickly and stopped the command from running but I have no idea how far it set the permissions.

I have had a couple of customers call me and say that they have issues with their websites like cannot log into the backend of wordpress and some of the plugins on the websites cannot access the data they should be able to in the database.

Could this command being run stop the database being run? The sites are up generally so I cannot see it being an MYSQLD thing.

I am running  CentOS release 6.5 (Final).

Will this have broken the server or do I have other issues? Is there a way to restore permissions? I have a backup from a week ago which I could compare the two permission but this is beyond my level of skill but happy to follow any guides (Correctly) this time!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question isn't on-topic for stackoverflow. I suggest you ask on the [Unix & Linux Stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, definitely not a programming question. This is server recovery

Comment: Sorry! I have posted over there. I will close this off.